# Is there any way to add custom login provider for Firebase mobile library.

Tags: firebase

The only reason that stops us using firebase is an absence of Vkontakte login ability. We have resources to develop such library addition by ourselves if we would have any docs/api/srcs for that.

For more info see:
http://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile

Comment: You can use any login schema you want with Firebase. Just generate your own tokens: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html

Comment: Also, discovered today that [Auth0](https://auth0.com) supports Firebase and Vkontakte. May want to give them a peek as well.